# Elasticsearch partial matching of a date field

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch

I have 100 records belongs to 2020-05-01 so once I type 2020 any possibility to return all the record which includes 2020?

Answer (score 0):

You can use range to filter on date field

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "date": {
            "gte": "2020||/y",
            "lte": "2020||/y",
            "format": "yyyy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can create a subfield of type text, which will split date in different tokens and allow you to use prefix and match queries

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": [
          "yyyy-MM-dd"
        ],
        "fields": {
          "text": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "date.text": "202"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index43",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "T9RwJXIBEIlbGJUZH3VX",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2020-06-01"
        }
      }
    ]
```

You will need a mix of queries on type text or type date based on your requirement

Comment: So any chance for filter data If I enter 202 or 05 like that?

Comment: @Oshini you will have to store date as text and use prefix query on it

Comment: This is my mapping   "createdAt" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "date_optional_time"
        }, you mean do I need to change it as string?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to filter the records based on the date, I would suggest using the range query as follows,

```
GET /my-index-name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
        "range" : {
          "createdAt" : {
            "from" : "2020-01-01",
            "to" : "2020-12-31"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to search the indexes based on multiple range queries, then please follow the below approach,

```
GET /my-index-name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
        "range" : {
          "createdAt" : {
            "from" : "2020-01-01",
            "to" : "2020-12-31"
            }
          }
        },
        {
        "range" : {
          "updatedAt" : {
            "from" : "2020-09-01",
            "to" : "2020-09-30"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```